# PDO insert not inserting

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to insert using a prepare PDO statement but it doesn't seem to be working how I would like it to be. Heres my code:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB', $username, $password);

$sql = "INSERT INTO posts (`text`,`name`) VALUES (:text,:username)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->bindParam(':text', $_GET['textField'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(':username', $_SESSION['myusername'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->execute();
print_r($q->errorInfo());
```

The issue is that this doesn't do anything and I am not sure why, I am using following the guidelines [here](http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/insert-update-and-delete-with-pdo/) to help me do it.

Edit: When I use print_r I get the following MySQL error:

```
Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''text','name') VALUES ('a','user')' at line 1 )
```

Comment: `TEXT` is a data type in MySQL. Try placing it in ticks.

Comment: How do you expect to get any error message (which might help you solve the problem) when you activate some kind of `ERRMODE_SILENT` ? Never do this not even in production environment. Always implement proper Exception handling.

Comment: @JohnConde I did that just now it didn't work sadly

Comment: You should be getting a query error. as @John Conde said `TEXT` is syntax in SQL. Does `print_r($q->errorInfo());` return anything for you?

Comment: Disable the `errmode_silent`. It's like stuffing your fingers into your ears and going "lalalalal can't hear you". If something's wrong, then DON'T disable the very tools that'd tell you what's wrong.

Comment: change column name `text` to something else

Answer (score 1):

Because text is a type in MySQL (look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-type-overview.html)), the query fails, because the syntax is wrong.

Add ticks around your text name and try again.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO posts (text,name) VALUES (:text,:username)";
                           ----
                     This is the error.
```